# Regex expression matcher in Camel

Tags: java, regex, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Iam trying to come up with a camel route, where a message will be sent to a jms queue only it if matches a given regex expression..

The route that I have is this:

```
<route id="testRoute">
    <from uri="jms:queue:Q.Order1" />
       <choice>
          <when>
             <simple>${body} regex '\w+.*'</simple>
             <to uri="jms:queue:Q.Order2"/>                             
          </when>
       </choice>        
</route>
```

If my msg. is this, it passes the regex just fine:

```
000000010020140507
```

However, if my msg is this, it fails:

```
00000001002     REXRYAN 004                                                           
00000002076006490993999900000
```

Why is the second message failing regex and what needs to be modified in the regex to pass the second message?
Thanks

Comment: Try using `[\s\S]` instead of the `.` in the regex?

Comment: changed the regex to '\w+\s\S*'....but did not work.

Comment: @user1717230 You did not use the square brackets?

Comment: '\w+[\s\S]*' worked..if you don't mind...could you explain what's going on..please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regex, `.` by default does not match newlines in most languages. In your situation, you have a multilined string and the body thus don't match the regex `\w+.*` since only the first line matches.

There are usually two ways to by-pass this:

1. Use a modifier/flag which makes `.` match newlines as well (but I don't know Camel, so I can't be sure how to do this, though adding `(?s)` at the beginning of the regex might make this work just as well since that's the equivalent of setting that particular modifier/flag).
2. Use a class containing both a character and its negation.

   For example, `[\s\S]` contains `\s` (whitespace character which includes newlines) and `\S` which matches non-whitespace characters. Together, they will match everything, because `\S` will match everything `\s` doesn't match.

   You could have used `[\w\W]` just as well to give the same result, or `[\d\D]` or similar constructs.

Comment: I knew the answer was one the way. +1'ed. :)

Comment: Would this also work if there were more than 2 lines...?